# MonoDroid speed

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm thinking of moving to MonoDroid, problem is the trial version only allows to test my code in emulator and everything runs slow in the emulator. my question (before i pay $400) is if the compiled code runs fast enough when deployed to the actual device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance, after app startup (~3s), is very good on a Nexus One, and is nothing like trying to run on the emulator.

Comment: went ahead and bought it. pretty happy with performance on the device.

Answer (score 3):

Performance on device is good for me too. Sometimes even faster than Dalvik. But yes, there exist a 2-3 second lag at start.

(This "answer" is intended to assure folks who wants to try MonoDroid that it works not only for one person :) )

Comment: It is possible to launch a native JAVA activity while the .net framework loads to give the illusion that the app. has started and is loading.
http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Slow-poor-performance-td4390223.html

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing far more than 2-3 second lag on startup. That is, the time from when I tap an application (and the log shows ActivityManager starting my Activity) to when `OnCreate` is first called.

I see 5 seconds or more on my HTC Legend with Android 2.2 (about 2 years old). For example:

```
2011-11-26 11:54:37.782 I 97/ActivityManager: Displayed activity
com.xxx.android/.SplashActivity: 5309 ms (total 5309 ms)
```

or the full log:

```
2011-11-26 11:54:32.372 I 97/ActivityManager: Starting activity: Intent {
act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.xxx.android/.SplashActivity }
2011-11-26 11:54:32.492 I 97/ActivityManager: Start proc com.xxx.android
for activity com.xxx.android/.SplashActivity: pid=23858 uid=10055
gids={1015, 3003}
2011-11-26 11:54:32.492 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23858 is creating
thread @dalvik/vm/Thread.c:1795
2011-11-26 11:54:32.502 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23859 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.522 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23858 is creating
thread @dalvik/vm/Thread.c:1795
2011-11-26 11:54:32.522 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23860 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.592 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23858 is creating
thread @dalvik/vm/Thread.c:1795
2011-11-26 11:54:32.592 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23861 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.602 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23858 is creating
thread @frameworks/base/libs/utils/Threads.cpp:139
2011-11-26 11:54:32.622 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23862 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.632 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23862 is creating
thread @frameworks/base/libs/utils/Threads.cpp:139
2011-11-26 11:54:32.642 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23863 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.712 I 73/pthread: ## thread 23864 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.712 I 73/pthread: ## thread 23865 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:32.792 I 23858/ActivityThread: Publishing provider
com.xxx.android.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
2011-11-26 11:54:32.842 D 23858/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib
/data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44e02348
2011-11-26 11:54:32.872 D 23858/dalvikvm: Added shared lib
/data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44e02348
2011-11-26 11:54:33.332 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23866 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:33.552 D 183/BT HS/HF: gsmAsuToSignal=6
2011-11-26 11:54:34.042 2 97/GpsLocationProvider:
ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE

2011-11-26 11:54:34.042 D 97/ConnectivityService: getMobileDataEnabled
returning true
2011-11-26 11:54:34.052 D 97/TelephonyRegistry: notifyDataConnection()
state=2isDataConnectivityPossible()true, reason=null
2011-11-26 11:54:34.052 D 97/TelephonyRegistry:
broadcastDataConnectionStateChanged()
state=CONNECTEDtypes=default,dun,supl, interfaceName=rmnet0
2011-11-26 11:54:34.072 D 97/NetworkLocationProvider:
onDataConnectionStateChanged 3
2011-11-26 11:54:34.092 D 97/ConnectivityService: getMobileDataEnabled
returning true
2011-11-26 11:54:34.122 D 97/MobileDataStateTracker: replacing old
mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for hipri
2011-11-26 11:54:34.122 D 97/MobileDataStateTracker: replacing old
mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for supl
2011-11-26 11:54:34.132 D 97/MobileDataStateTracker: replacing old
mInterfaceName (rmnet0) with rmnet0 for dun
2011-11-26 11:54:34.222 2 97/AlarmManager: Adding Alarm{4521c788 type 2
com.google.android.apps.maps} Dec 15 09:35:32 am
2011-11-26 11:54:34.362 I 97/LSState:
EventReceiver:android.intent.action.NOTIFICATION_UPDATE
2011-11-26 11:54:34.822 D 23858/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 11754
objects / 463408 bytes in 67ms

2011-11-26 11:54:35.042 D 23858/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10024
objects / 469712 bytes in 62ms

2011-11-26 11:54:36.372 I 97/LSState:
EventReceiver:android.intent.action.NOTIFICATION_UPDATE
2011-11-26 11:54:37.462 I 23858/pthread: ## thread 23867 is created success
2011-11-26 11:54:37.782 I 97/ActivityManager: Displayed activity
com.xxx.android/.SplashActivity: 5309 ms (total 5309 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The slowness is due to the Android emulator - running on an actual device is fine for MonoDroid.